# html5 template tag: fallback for content access

Tags: html, fallback, javafx-webengine, html5-template

I am using a template tag in a webkit browser (JavaFX WebView 2.2) to store elements that I may clone and append on the main part of the document.

However, I can't access its content using **templateElement.content** (the HTML5 standard). Instead, I use jQuery to get the elements inside the template TAG with the selector "**#templateElement div**".

Seems the template tag is not yet fully supported (inner scripts also run), although its contents are not rendered.

My fear is that, when the template tag becomes supported, the way to get its contents will break and my page will stop working.

What is the recommended way of getting template contents regardless future implementation changes?

HTML:

```
<template id="templateElement">
    <div>Clone Me!</div>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getContentsCurrent() {
    var toBeCloned = $("#templateElement div")[0];
    //append where needed...
}

function getContentsFuture() {
    var toBeCloned = templateElement.content.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    //append where needed...
}
```

***EDIT***

I think jQuery won't be able to handle this automatically, even in the future, because the template "innerHTML" is purposely routed to **content** so that it becomes inaccessible to the DOM (so no selector touches it accidentally).

Comment: Eduardo, can you created a fiddle to reproduce the problem? I would gladly help, but I am lazy to do so from scratch :)

Comment: Well, the problem is not happening yet. I can get the div inside the template with getContentsCurrent(). But, in future releases of JavaFX, when template is implemented according to the HTML5 specification, then the code may break, as I think the innerHTML of templates will only be accessible using the content property of the template element. Then, it will be necessary to use getContentsFuture(). Is it possible to downgrade the browser in the fiddle to test fallbacks?

Comment: Eduardo, you are trying to solve a problem which does not exist yet. I believe it is better to prepare for the problem: make the given thing as atomic as possible, so if the problem actually occurs in the future, you can change it. In the meantime, register to newsletters to know about the nature of the change in advance, if possible ;)

Comment: Yeah, I want to solve it before it happens. Changing after the problem arises is not difficult, but it could happen when I am too much busy. It would be bad for the users to have a sudden break on the page, even if for some days. I wanted some code capable of working both ways, now and in the future. The selected answer made me think about general solutions for fallbacks, and they seem simpler than I though before asking the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test if the `content` feature exists before:

```
function getContents() {
  var toBeCloned;
  if ( templateElement.content )
    toBeCloned = templateElement.content.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  else
    toBeCloned = templateElement.querySelector("div");
  //append where needed...
}
```

Another way:

```
var content = templateElement.content || templateElement
var toBeCloned = content.querySelector( "div" )
//...
```

Comment: Indeed, that is the general fallback solution. Good to learn so much other things when asking questions on SO!